# PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager for a single host/route

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, resttemplate

So I have a spring application and I use PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager to creation a connection pool for all http requests that go out of this application. I only have one host to call which means there is only one route.

```
 @Bean
      public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager getPHCM() {
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager phcm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        phcm.setMaxTotal(50);
        phcm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
        return phcm;
      }
```

I am wondering if this configuration will create and reserve all 50 connections for one single route that I have ? I find setting MaxPerRoute value redundant but not sure if that is also what I need for my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if this configuration will create and reserve all 50 connections

No, it will not. HttpClient will keep persistent connection alive as long as there is room in the connection pool but it will not proactively create connections.

Comment: How does connection pool work then? Is it not suppose to proactively keep those many connections ready so that connections don’t need to be opened and closed everytime there is an incoming request ? I didn’t quite understand your answer in connection with a connection pool

Comment: The pool manager will not proactively pre-populate the pool. The pool is always empty in the beginning. After each request execution the pool manager determines whether or not the connection released back can be kept alive and re-used. Persistent connections stay in the pool until they expire or get closed by either of the endpoints.

Comment: So you mean to say each persistent connection created by httpclient after a consumer thread releases it goes back to the pool and an be reused by another thread ? So that means the pool will only have a connection looked inside of it when it was created by an incoming request and not proactively? Is this a correct understanding ?

Comment: Yes, it is. This is the whole point of HTTP connection persistence.

Comment: Also, for One single route, based on the config I have, would it keep the max count of 50 for that solo route ?

Comment: Yes, it would. Why would not it?

Comment: I wasn't sure about the config and how it works. Now I know. Thanks for your help. appreciate that